# Electron Vue app launches wth 401 unauthorized

Tags: sqlite, vue.js, electron

I cloned a repo from https://github.com/luwanquan/electron-vue-sqlite3-demo to learn setting up sqlite in my electron app. Faced several issues solved it and now there is no issue, but when I do npm run dev, the app launches but it shows up with 401 Authorized.[image]

What may be the reason? Any help would be appreciated. thankyou!

Comment: Do you see what is in console?
Try ctrl+shift+i and see console

Comment: There is a warning mentioning: Electron Security Warning (Insecure Content-Security-Policy) This renderer process has either no Content Security
      Policy set or a policy with "unsafe-eval" enabled. This exposes users of
      this app to unnecessary security risks.
 
For more information and help, consult
https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security.
 This warning will not show up
once the app is packaged.

Comment: I cloned repo to and all work perfectlly http://i.imgur.com/5fqdFv4.png
But before get error that module sqlite3 not found.
For fix his install `npm install electron-rebuild` and after  `./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild -w sqlite3 -p`